# zsh function to put arbitrary string into the line editor

Tags: zsh

I'd like to create a zsh-function that will put a computed string into the line editor, e.g.

```
insert_foo() {
  # Do something that will put the string "foo" in the line editor
}

$ insert_foo
$ foo # <- "foo" appears in the line editor, without actually executing it
```

I know this is possible within a zle-widget, but can it also be it's own command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use [`print -z`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print):

```
insert_foo() {
  print -z "foo"
}
```

Here is the zsh doc's copy for [`print -z`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print):

> `print` `[ -abcDilmnNoOpPrsSz ]` `[ -u n ]` `[ -f format ]` `[ -C cols ]`
>   ...
>   `-z`  Push the arguments onto the editing buffer stack,  separated by spaces.
>
> --- [zshbuiltin(1), shell builtin commands, `print`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)